# How to enable import form data in Adobe Reader

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

I currently have a pdf form open in Adobe Reader for which I would like to fill out using an XML file. However, under the extended features tab, the option to import data is greyed out (exporting data works perfectly however). How can I enable this feature in Reader?

Comment: Which version of Reader are you using? Is the form a PDF (Acroforms, using Acrobat to create), or an XFA (XFA, using LiveCycle Designer to create) document?

Comment: @MaxWyss I don't know. The PDF form is generated within an application which I believe uses LifeCycle Designer.

Comment: If it is an XFA form, try applying Extended Rights using Acrobat Pro. No guarantee, but it should get you closer.